# HashSet internally uses hashmap for its implementation, then why is hashmap faster than hashset?

Tags: java

HashSet internally uses hashmap for its implementation, then why is hashmap faster than hashset?

I tried reading the above mentioned post in search but was unable to find a clear answer

Comment: Not that I dont believe you, but can you please post some code to show what you are talking about?

Comment: read this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278995/why-hashmap-is-faster-than-hashset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because HashSet uses a HashMap.  It must incur the cost of using a HashMap, plus the overhead of the HashSet itself.

Comment: To clarify the above, a `Set` implements `Collection` which `Map` does not. Therefore a `HashSet` must maintain some iterable reference to the elements. It uses the `Map` to check for existence but must still add the element to the iterable collection.

Answer (score 0):

in a `HashMap` you store element value pairs when in a `Set` you store only element.

When you call `add(value)` for `Set` actually you call `put` as well (for `HashMap`).

`Set` *backed by* `HashMap`